# Oracle Python callproc() Script stops

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I have a hughe problem.
I created a procedure and stored it in my OracleDB.
Now I want to execute the procedure, but its not working. There is no Error-Message Occuring, it just stops and dont continue after the first callproc call. Anybody any ideas?

!Autoincrement is enabled for the whole script!

`import cx_Oracle dsn= cx_Oracle.makedsn("**********,1521,"orcl") 
db= cx_Oracle.connect('******','*******',dsn) 
db.autocommit = True cur = db.cursor() 
cur.callproc("UPDATE_MISSING_VALUES", ['GENDER','***_PRE',1])`

The Procedure is found and if I change the parameters, an SQL Error occurs. But if I let it like that, nothing happens.

If I run that query in SQL-Developer, it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I have actually now idea why, but the most important thing is that it works.
Is it possible, that the reason is that I made a

```
COMMIT;
```

Statement in my DB?? After that it worked suddenly.

Comment: Sounds highly likely.  If a table is locked waiting for a commit or rollback, then any other DML like UPDATE on it will block.